# Parsing Wikipedia List and Storing Result into 2D Array

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

[This is the page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_company_name_etymologies) I am interested in parsing. After parsing, I want to store the result into a 2-D array. Can anyone please throw light on how I should go about this? Here is the code from my attempt using BeautifulSoup. `html` contains the html from the above url.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
temp = soup.find_all('li')
#for x in temp :
#    print x.text

table = []
for x in temp :
    row = []
    index = x.text.find(' - ',0)
    row.append(x.text[0:index-1])
    row.append(x.text[index+3:])
    table.append(row)

for row in table :
    print row
```

Comment: What have you [tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? Please paste some code.

Comment: Now the moron came here in hope of getting his problems cleared. Alas, such a moron !!

Comment: You said you'd tried BS and lxml, how about posting the result/error here ?

Comment: @AnantSharma, I just want to emphasize that _I_ never intended to call you a moron. I just saw that this was your first question and thought I should introduce you to the conventions of the site. Since you tried BeautifulSoup, perhaps you should paste the code the resulted from your attempt? See also this excellent advice from the [dark overlord of StackOverflow](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: @senderle Point noted.
This is the code I wrote. html contains the page source.
I tried pasting the code but it wasn't getting indented. So I am posting a link.
http://ideone.com/CgiKc
This is the output I got for the first 3 rows ( its 684 lines in total ).

Comment: @AnantSharma, if you highlight your code and press `ctrl-K` or the code formatting button (`{}`) at the top of the edit window, it will automatically indent the highlighted code by four spaces. The result should be properly formatted code.

Comment: ideone.com doesn't have BeautifulSoup installed. If you have the same error in your computer, it mean you either don't have BeautifulSoup too or forgot to import it.

Comment: @Dikei : That link is just for the code as I wasn't able to paste it here. I am not as a big a moron a you are making out to be me :D